# How to call a Rails named route when testing controllers with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to test the permalink action in my articles controller, which is using a named route (/permalink/terms-of-use):

```
map.permalink 'permalink/:permalink', 
              :controller => :articles, :action => :permalink, :as => :permalink
```

This is the spec:

```
describe "GET permalink" do
  it "should visit an article" do
    get "/permalink/@article.permalink"
  end
end
```

But I get this error:

ActionController::RoutingError in 'ArticlesController permalink renders the page'
No route matches {:controller=>"articles", :action=>"/permalink/@article.permalink"}

UPDATE:

any idea how to write the GET?

Answer (score 4):

The error is because you're passing an entire URL to a method that expects a name of one of the controller's action methods. If I understand correctly, you're trying to test several things at once.

Testing that a route has a name is different from testing a route is different from testing a controller action. Here's how I test a controller action (this probably comes as no surprise). Note that I'm matching your naming, not recommending what I'd use.

In spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb,

```
describe ArticlesController do
  describe '#permalink' do
    it "renders the page" do
      # The action and its parameter are both named permalink
      get :permalink :permalink => 666
      response.should be_success
      # etc.
    end
  end
end
```

Here's how I test a named route with only rspec-rails:

In spec/routing/articles_routing_spec.rb,

```
describe ArticlesController do
  describe 'permalink' do

    it 'has a named route' do
      articles_permalink(666).should == '/permalink/666'
    end

    it 'is routed to' do
      { :get => '/permalink/666' }.should route_to(
        :controller => 'articles', :action => 'permalink', :id => '666')
    end

  end
end
```

Shoulda's route matcher is more succinct while still providing a nice description and failure message:

```
describe ArticlesController do
  describe 'permalink' do

    it 'has a named route' do
      articles_permalink(666).should == '/permalink/666'
    end

    it { should route(:get, '/permalink/666').to(
      :controller => 'articles', :action => 'permalink', :id => '666' })

  end
end
```

AFAIK neither RSpec nor Shoulda have a specific, concise way of testing named routes, but you could write your own matcher.

Comment: with our first example I get a routing error, i need to test 'permalink/a_name'. Sorry my question was unclear. I need to test the permalink action, but I am using a named route. I need to know the right syntax for get ...

Comment: When you test the action, don't worry about its route. Just test the action directly as in the first code example above. Testing the route is a different issue; see the other two examples for that.

Comment: your first example does not work because a get is created having articles in the url, i.e. /articles/permalink/name_of_article but I need /permalink/name_of_the_article and RSpec does not allow me to do that.

Comment: I adjusted my examples to match what I think you're trying to do. The important point is not the specifics of the route, though, but the difference between testing an action and testing a route. In an RSpec controller test, get's first parameter is the name of an action, not a path. Provide the rest of the information in the path using parameters.

Comment: Your first example is very similar to my test, but it gives: ActionController::RoutingError in 'ArticlesController GET permalink renders the page'
No route matches {:controller=>"articles", :permalink=>"link", :action=>"permalink"}

Comment: the url is 'permalink/name_of-artile', not 'articles/permalink/name-of-article'. With 'get :permalink :permalink => 666' it creates a url with article in front... the url is not the routes.

Comment: Make sure you include all the parameters in your request, or the route will not be matched... use `rake routes` to check what parameters your route requires.

Answer (score 0):

```
describe "GET permalink" do
  it "should visit an article" do
    get "/permalink/#{@article.permalink}"
  end
end
```

Comment: No. I get this: ActionController::RoutingError in 'ArticlesController GET permalink should visit an article'
No route matches {:controller=>"articles", :action=>"/permalink/link"}